# using animatorSet.playTogether(Collection<Animator> items) in a function

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-animation

I've created a function that gets a string. I then start a loop that runs through the characters of the string, and then acts based on the character with a switch (each character has a different case).

```
public void setBlimps(String locations){
    final RelativeLayout game = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    // getting the layout
    for(int i = 0; i < locations.length(); i++){
        switch(locations.charAt(i)){
```

^The beginning fo the loop^

All the cases are quite similar, for example:

```
            case 'A':
                final ImageView blimpA = new ImageView(this);
                blimpA.setImageResource(R.drawable.explosion);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,150);
                layoutParamsA.setMargins(200, 200, 200, 200);
                blimpA.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsA);
                blimpA.setPivotX(150);
                blimpA.setPivotY(150);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        game.addView(blimpA);
                    }
                });
                final ObjectAnimator animA1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(blimpA,"translationX",0,-200).setDuration(1000);
                final ObjectAnimator animA2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(blimpA,"translationY",0,-200).setDuration(1000);
                animators.add(animA1);
                animators.add(animA2);
                break;
```

In each case I want to create an ImageView with very specific parameters : resource, pivotX/Y, margins, etc (All cases can be functionalized, but it's a bit complex).
Then I add it to the relativeLayout by using runOnUiThread.

I then create the specific animators of the ImageView(Property Animation) and add them to my Global ArrayList called "animators".

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animatorSet.playTogether(animators);// this doesn't work
        }
    });
```

^This is called upon exiting the For loop and, as I understood, should play all the animators I've given on the specified ImageViews at the same time. *The animatorSet is global

**When I give the function the string "AE" and run the code it succeeds in creating caseA's ImageView, but doesn't play its animations. In addition, it does not create the caseE ImageView and doesn't play its animations as well.**

*The function is called in a TimerTask (Doesn't seem to be the problem)

*Any help with making it work or making it more efficient will be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: Why don't you use ViewPropertyAnimator? It's easy and simple af.

Comment: When I call the function the string specifies which animations I want played together. These are not the same animations every time, each string has a different number of animations running on different views that I need to play together. From quickly reading this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html
I do see that using a ViewPropertyAnimator will be easier than using six Object Animator's, but this isn't the issue.

Comment: You mean, in your AE example, each character will be in a separate ImageView and that each character will have a different animator object? These animator objects are all added in the animatorSet ArrayList, right? I've also done something similar but using ViewPropertyAnimator. I'm pretty sure VPA will do your job just fine. Also maybe you need to use OnGlobalLayoutListener and then call start() on your animators after your views have been laid out. It may be that your animators are being started before layout of your views.

Comment: I understand that you are suggesting that in each case ,where I create an ImageView. That I would then right:
blimpA.animate().translationX(value).translationY(value); 
But I also want the animations to run together.
Also there's is the main issue that it doesn't even add the ImageView I've created in the "E" case to the layout. I've checked and that is not the reason the playTogether method isn't working because it still doesn't play the animations when I am only attempting to animate the ImageView of case "A" that did appear on the UI.

Comment: Calling animator1.start() and then animator2.start() will make animator1 and animator2 run simultaneously, with ViewPropertyAnimator. But okay, let's put that aside for now. The reason why your **A** TextView is not animating is most likely because you're calling the `playTogether()` method before the TextView has been laid out on the screen. You might need to attach an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` interface to your **A** view and call the startTogether() method inside `onGlobalLayout()` method of the interface. This will ensure that any attempt to animate the view occurs after it's layout is done

Comment: A better alternative to `OnGlobalLayoutListener` is to use `View.post(Runnable runnable)`. If you put the playTogether() method inside `runnable`, it'll make sure that the animation occurs when the view is first drawn on the screen.